# Request class: rules depends on amounht of elements

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using request class in order to valdiate forms but I have a problem. Look at this code

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|between:6,50',
        'category_id' => 'required|integer|between:1,10'
    ];
}
```

It works correctly but amount of category will be change. I can solve my problem, if I use validate method inside my controller's method:

```
$count = Category::count();
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|string|between:6,50',
    'category_id' => 'required|integer|between:1,' . $count
]);
```

How can I solve my problem by using request class?

Comment: i think you can use `$count = Category::count();` inside your request class

Answer (score 4):

Your validation does not make much sense at the moment, you are validating against some arbitrary number that may or may not exist in your database.

I am going to assume that you only want to accept category ids that exist in the database, so I would use the `exists` rule:

```php
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|string|between:6,50',
    'category_id' => 'required|integer|exists:categories,id'
]);
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-exists):

```php
exists:table,column
```

> The field under validation must exist on a given database table.

Basic Usage Of Exists Rule

```php
'state' => 'exists:states'
```

> If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

Specifying A Custom Column Name

```php
'state' => 'exists:states,abbreviation'
```